# Dynamic goal tolerance

Tags: navigation, c++, base-local-planner, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there was any way to change the yaw_goal_tolerance and xy_goal_tolerance of e.g. the base_local_planner.

There are several situations where we want to apply a very small tolerance (+decrease accs and vels). But since this should definitely not be the default we want to be capable of 'dynamically reconfigure' those params. Unfortunately, those parameters are missing from the according reconfigure message.

What recently came to my mind was killing and restarting the node and apply a different set of default parameters. In my opinion, that would be a really dirty hack though.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36432/dynamic-goal-tolerance/) by [Random-I-Am](https://answers.ros.org/users/2088/random-i-am/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2018-09-28**:
Did you hack into move base to add the dynamic reconfig for these?
If yes, could you please share that part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, AFAIK there is no way to dynamically reconfigure these planner parameters. If you are serious about this, hack into `move_base` and have it read these params from a callback , like  `plannerParamsUpdateCallback` . Killing and restarting the node would be terrible, to say the least.

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2012-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0